# What is this error Found widget <g:ListBox class='dropdownbx' name='deleteDigits' ui:field='deletedigs'> in an HTML context

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I get this error when I run my Gwt app

Found widget  in an HTML context

Here is a snippet of the xml that it complains about:

```
    <!-- ... -->
    <g:HTML ui:field="localPanel">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Local</legend>
        <label for="btn" >BTN:</label><input type="text" ui:field="btn" class="txtbx numeric" maxlength="10" name='btn'/>
        <label for="stdprt">SDT PRT:</label><input type="text" ui:field="stdprt" class="txtbx" readonly="readonly" name='stdPrt'/>
        <label for="rateArea">Rate Area:</label><input type="text" ui:field="ratearea" class="txtbx" readonly="readonly" name='rateArea'/>
        <br/>
        <label for="deleteDigits">Delete Digits:</label><g:ListBox ui:field='deletedigs' class="dropdownbx" name='deleteDigits'/>
    </fieldset>
    </g:HTML>
    <g:Button ui:field="submit2">Submit</g:Button>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are certain tags (those which GWT says are make an "HTML context") that can't have widgets inside them. For instance, `<g:HTML><g:Label /></g:HTML>` is illegal because a  only expects HTML elements and not widgets. However, if you change that to `<g:HTMLPanel><g:Label /></g:HTMLPanel>` it will work.

The particular snippet triggering the error in your code is the `<g:ListBox ui:field='deletedigs' class="dropdownbx" name='deleteDigits'/>` that's contained in the `<g:HTML ui:field="localPanel">`. Make that `<g:HTML>` into a `<g:HTMLPanel>` and it should all work.