# Compile Error: Found widget in an HTML context Element

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745211/what-is-this-error-found-widget-glistbox-classdropdownbx-namedeletedigits) but my I can't see what could possibly be the problem in my own code.  Here is the my uibinding xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui' xmlns:a='urn:import:com.google.gwt.app.client'>
    <ui:style field='iphone' src='Render.css' />        
<div id='iHeader'>
    <div
        style='display:block; opacity:1; -webkit-tranform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);'>
        <a>
            <span id='waHeadTitle'
                style='display:block; -webkit-tranform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);'>
                <g:HTML ui:field="title" />
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Then I get the error message: Found widget in an HTML context Element `<g:HTML ui:field='title'>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the root element of the widget was a div.  I think that's fine as long as the whole widget is pure HTML, but if you want to mix HTML and widgets, the root has to be HTMLPanel.