# GWT-2.5.1:How can I add the outline parameter of CSS to DialogBox using UIBinder correctly?

Tags: java, css, gwt, user-interface, uibinder

I want to add "outline" parameter of CSS.
The Java Code.

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class MyDialogBox extends DialogBox {

    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyDialogBox> {

    }

    public MyDialogBox() {
        setWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

The XML Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <ui:style>
        .panel {
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            outline: 15px solid blue;
            background-color: ivory;
            /*margin: 15px;*/
        }
    </ui:style>

    <g:TabLayoutPanel barUnit='EM' barHeight='1' styleName="{style.panel}">
        <g:tab>
            <g:header size='20'>tab1</g:header>
            <g:Label>label1</g:Label>
        </g:tab>
        <g:tab>
            <g:header size='20'>tab2</g:header>
            <g:Label>label2</g:Label>
        </g:tab>
    </g:TabLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The outline-border doesn't display.
[image]
But it is displayed when I remove the comment-out of the margin parameter.
[image]
How can I add the outline parameter correctly without margin parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `border` property if you don't want to have to add `margin`.
A solution is to wrap with anoter div.

Example (*not tested, they may be need some adaptation*) :

```
<ui:style>
    .panel {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        /* DELETED border: 15px solid blue; */
        background-color: ivory;
        /* DELETED margin: 15px; */
    }
    .subpanel {
        border: 15px solid blue;
    }
</ui:style>

<div class="panel">
    <g:TabLayoutPanel barUnit='EM' barHeight='1' styleName="{style.subpanel}">
        <g:tab>
            <g:header size='20'>tab1</g:header>
            <g:Label>label1</g:Label>
        </g:tab>
        <g:tab>
            <g:header size='20'>tab2</g:header>
            <g:Label>label2</g:Label>
        </g:tab>
    </g:TabLayoutPanel>
</div>
```

I suggest you to See the [documentation of w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) for more details about the `outline` property.

I wich this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was solved. And this was also usuful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418634/compile-error-found-widget-in-an-html-context-element